# How to align LI vertically middle

Tags: html, css, html-lists, vertical-alignment

I've HTML UL LI tags arranged as mentioned below:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body style="margin: 0px;">
    <ul style="display: table; width:98%; margin: 5px; padding: 0; min-width:500px;">
     <li style="display:table-row; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
       <ul style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
          <li style="float:left; text-align:center; display:table-cell; width:5%; min-height: 50px; ">A</li>
          <li style="float:left; display:table-cell; width:87%; min-height: 50px; ">B</li>
          <li style="float:left; text-align:center; display:table-cell; width:8%; min-height: 50px; "><input type="submit" name="one" id="one" value="one"></li></ul>
    </li>
    <li style="display:table-row; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
       <ul style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
          <li style="float:left; display:table-cell; width:92%; min-height: 100px; ">
            <div style="width:100%; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #cfcfcf; border-radius:10px; color:black; border:1px solid #e5e5e5; min-height: 100px;">Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. SamplText here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. </div>
         </li>
         <li style="float:left;text-align:center; display:table-cell; width:8%; min-height: 100px; "> &nbsp; C</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li style="display:table-row; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
      <ul style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
        <li style="float:left; text-align:center; display:table-cell; width:5%; min-height: 100px; "><input type="radio" name="optia" value="a" id="optia">A</li>
         <li style="float:left; display:table-cell; width:87%; min-height: 100px; "><div style="width:100%; box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #cfcfcf; border-radius:10px; color:black; border:1px solid #e5e5e5; min-height: 100px;">Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. Sample Text here. </div></li>
         <li style="float:left; text-align:center; display:table-cell; width:8%; min-height: 100px; "> &nbsp; C</li>
         </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

It gives output as mentioned below:

[image]

How Can i Align RADIO Boxes and Text "C" in the last column vertically middle with the LI ; along RED Line Drawn?

Comment: @j08691 ; Sorry I didn't get you? What is Ug? [Inline CSS are added in above post just to give look and feel of UI, in real code CSS are external]

Comment: Ug is me throwing my hands in the air trying to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Your going to want to add a vertical-align: bottom; to align it to the red line.  But I would really avoid using inline CSS as it will muck up your html from looking clean and crisp.

```
style="vertical-align: bottom" // add to your li for the C
```

Comment: I added vertical-align: bottom to LI for C ; but it's now working. [In read code CSS is external]

Answer (score 0):

By Adding TOP & BOTTOM PADDING ; i managed to align radio button vertically centered with LI. I don't think this is fool-proof solution; But as a work-around it works.